# Array and classes

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following problem.

I have file en-EN.php - where I keep all my feature translations in a way such as:

```
<?php     
    $lang = array(
        'Index' => 'Index'
    );
?>
```

and I include this file on the header of the page, so that I can access it, like this: `$lang['Index']`.

The problem is the following. 
When I create another file, such as `User.class.php` and I try to include this translation array inside it does not allow me to use it.

My User.class.php file for example:

```
 <?php
    class User {
        function showIndex() {
            echo $lang['Index'];        
        }
    }
```

However, this way it does not allow me to show the actual word. What can be the problem?

My include in the header:

```
include '/lang/en-EN.php';
include '/theme/classes/User.class.php';

$user = new User();

$user->showIndex();
```

I need to pass the $lang array somehow, but I have no idea how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class and the method of the class have different variable scope so they cant see the "$lang" variable. You can do something like this:

```
include "en-EN.php";
include "~/User.classs.php";
$user = new User($lang);
$user->showIndex();
```

And the class should look like this:

```
class User {
    protected $lang;
    public function __construct($lang) {
        $this->lang = $lang;
    }
    public function test() {
        echo $this->lang['Index'];
    }
}
```

In general it is good idea to take a look at [gettext](http://php.net/manual/bg/book.gettext.php)

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about gettext, however, there is no need of this in this project. I will try your solution in a minute!

Answer (score 1):

Your `$lang` variable is not accessible within the scope of a function or method. You have to use `global` to import it.

```
function showIndex() {
    global $lang;
    echo $lang['Index'];        
}
```

Comment: Using globals is not good idea - [PHP The Right Way - Register Globals](http://www.phptherightway.com/#register_globals)

Comment: @gotha Register globals and accessing a variable in the global scope are not the same thing. There is nothing wrong with using `global` (in general).